# Javascript Issue - HTML division Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in the learning phase the code works fine no issues, however I need to add the below features.

1. When clicking the mouse on the calculate button it does the calculation and spits the results out correct, however my question is I'd want to use the physical keyboard "enter key" to execute/press the calculate button.
2. Also I need the form to reset after 5 seconds automatically, how can I do that ?

.

```
<script Language="Javascript">function Calc(myform){var enternumber1=document.myform.number1.value;var enternumber1=parseFloat(enternumber1,10);if(isNaN(enternumber1)||(enternumber1<0)){alert(" Enter a valid number! ");document.myform.number1.value="";document.myform.number1.focus();}else{var enternumber2=document.myform.number2.value;var enternumber2=parseFloat(enternumber2,10);if(isNaN(enternumber2)||(enternumber2<0)){alert(" Enter a valid number! ");document.myform.number2.value="";document.myform.number2.focus();}else
document.myform.number3.value=enternumber1/enternumber2;}}</script>
    <form name="myform">
        <br />
        <b>Enter your first number:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input maxlength="" name="number1" size=" " type="text" /><br />
        <br />
        <b>Enter your second number:</b> <input maxlength="" name="number2" size="" type="text" /><br />
        <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="button" onclick="Calc(myform)" type="button" value="Calculate" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Reset" type="Reset" /><br />
        <br />
        <b>The result is :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input maxlength="" name="number3" size="" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;</form>
```

Comment: Cool. What's the question?

Comment: How did this get an upvote?! I can possibly, sort-of see not down-voting, but an upvote is either a sock puppet or someone playing games.

Comment: 1. When I hit the enter key on my keyboard I want the calculate button to execute.
2. The reset button should auto reset after 5 seconds automatically.

Comment: Right, but what's the question?

Comment: `The reset button should auto reset after 5 seconds automatically` what effect does resetting a reset button have, automatically or not - did you mean the form needs to reset after 5 seconds (automatically)?

Comment: could you possibly make the code harder to read? javascript in one line? why?

Comment: The calculate button works when I click using the mouse and it shows me the correct answer, however I want to be able to use the "enter key on my keyboard" I don't want to click the mouse, I want hit the enter key physically to execute the calculate button.

Comment: OK, and again, **what is the question?** What are you having trouble with? What errors or roadblocks are you encountering, and what have you done to troubleshoot? All you're doing is restating what you want to do.

Comment: Hey Steve. You'll probably want to review the 'How do I ask a good question" post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask That should help you restructure your question in a way that might earn you some better, more positive feedback.

Comment: Yes I'm checking it also I've edited my post to make things easier to understand.

Comment: Your edits still haven't added a **question**. You know, something that ends with a `?` mark? Is your question how to make JavaScript wait for five seconds? If so, look into `setTimeout`. Is it how to listen for the Enter key? Then Google "javascript detect enter key" and look at the results.

Comment: Here is another post from the help pages abut [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Take the time to clean up your question and focus on asking specifics

Answer (score 0):

Please try to be clear in whatever you are asking. Lets move to your query now:

From your query I can understand that you are facing issues in doing 2 things:

1. Calling your Calc('myform') function when Enter key is pressed in second input field. - I am not covering validation of form(should have validation function,to be called before calling Calc() function). Just add an id to both the form tag as well as the second input field.Let say you add myForm and num2 ids in form and second input field respectively. 
   Once added you can use following function:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('num2').onkeypress = function (event) {
           if (event.keyCode == 13) {
               Calc(myform);
           }
       };
   </script>
   ```

**Note:**In this function we are checking every key which is getting pressed when our cursor is in num2 field, if the key pressed is having code 13,which is the keycode of enter key, I am just calling the same function Calc() which you are already using.So it will do the same what its doing on click of Calculate button.

2. For resetting your form in every 5 seconds.Please add this function:

   ```
   function resetForm() {
       document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
   }

   setInterval(resetForm, 5000);
   ```

**Note:** We are calling setInterval function here to reset your form in every 5seconds.Please dont forget to add myForm id in your form.